# Debugger not hitting break point in the android application

Tags: android

I have created a empty android application and inserted one break point in onCreateView event the break point is not hitting. android developer studio version is Build: v22.6.2-1085508
Not sure why it's not hitting. The break is hitting some times not always what will be the reason any help?

Answer (score 0):

The Break point is hitted every time when your code reaches up to that statement.
Hence Please make sure that your is reaching the breakpoint S

Comment: Yes I put some log comments.Its showing but only break point not hitting